# Plot the centroid of four values on a radar chart

Tags: javascript, php, plot

04/09/15

Update: I know now how to mathematically get the coordinates that I needed. Now the issue is how to code it.

Calculate the centroid of four x,y coordinates

Find the centroid of triangle 1
(x1+x2+x4)/3
(y1+y2+y4)/3

The result will be a coordinate such as (12,10.6). Fractions are possible.
Find the centroid of triangle 2 
(x2+x3+x4)/3
(y2+y3+y4)/3

The result will be a coordinate such as (8.3,7.0). Fractions are possibly and should be limited to one digit.

Find the midpoint of the line between the centroids of triangle 1 and triangle 2
(x1+x2)/2
(y1+y2)/2

The result will be a coordinate that represents the centroid of the four original x,y coordinates.

Original post content below here>>
I would like to plot the centroid of four values, which are stored in mysql, on a radar chart (which forms a quadrilateral). The values are all between 0 and 100.

The following sample radar chart shows values of A=80 (18,18) B=30 (13,7) C=40 (6,6) and D=70 (3,17), (x=0 and y=0) in the lower left corner.

I can manually find location of the centroid by creating two triangles, finding the centroid of those, then drawing a line between them, the center point of that line is the centroid. Using this method the centroid of these values is approximately (10,12).

How can this be coded to determine that the plot point is (10,12)?

[image]